# Find Friends In-Game

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there a way to mark friends you have queued with (or just steam friends) on the radar/minimap or even elsewhere?

Every time I play a game with friends it's hard to spot them in the start of a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not officially, although you could both use `cl_color` to set your preferred colour and confirm it to each other.

- cl_color 0 = yellow
- cl_color 1 = purple
- cl_color 2 = green
- cl_color 3 = blue
- cl_color 4 = orange

This will only worked on ranked.